# Spring Autowire mechanics with plain XML configuration

Tags: spring, autowired, spring-ioc

I am trying to understand the various Spring bean configurations, and at the outset, trying the traditional XML way.

Now I came to know for dependency injection,the "basic" methods are `setter` injection and `constructor` injection.

Thus far, good.

I also came to know that one more method which Spring provided is by `Autowire`. In `Autowire` we have many options, like: `byType`, `byName`, `constructor`.

Now when I dig more about `Autowire` option , it seems that for `byType` and `byName` to work there needs to have `setter` method to be present while for `Autowire` by `constructor` there should be matching constructor.

Is this correct?

Now, if `Autowire` internally uses constructor or setter, then why do we have this option present at all?

Can anyone help me understand this?